# How can I fade in images on page load one after the other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created the following code that on page load adds opacity: 1 to all divs on the page.  In doing so all the images are seen on pageload, but I want each to fade in slowly and after one has completely loaded/is visible I want the 2nd image to load exactly the same then followed by the third.

How can I accomplish this via the code below; what needs to be changed/added?  Please note it must use pure Javascript; no CSS3 or jQuery as the proprietary framework I'm working in requires pure JS.

```js
var imageOne = document.getElementById('imageOne');
var imageTwo = document.getElementById('imageTwo');
var imageThr = document.getElementById('imageThr');

function fadeIn() {
  imageOne.style.opacity = '1';
  imageTwo.style.opacity = '1';
  imageThr.style.opacity = '1';
}
```

```css
#imageOne {
  background: url('https://thingiverse-production-new.s3.amazonaws.com/renders/16/04/2d/b5/ed/smiley_face_thumb_small.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
}
#imageTwo {
  background: url('http://www.mpaart.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/twitter-logo-round-50x50.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
}
#imageThr {
  background: url('http://orig08.deviantart.net/24c1/f/2009/238/d/8/small_50x50__png_clock_pic_by_counter_countdown_ip.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="fadeIn()">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="imageOne"></div>
    <div id="imageTwo"></div>
    <div id="imageThr"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As a note for you. You can use jquery if the only thing you are worrying about is it working in ie 6+. https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: As another note. You are restricting the use of css3 but then you use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity I could be reading that wrong but i think opacity only came in at css3.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS transitions, which is faster and won't require jQuery.

```
.fadeIn {
    transition: opacity 1.25s;
}
```

Add the class `fadeIn` to your image elements, and now it'll fade.

To make it fade one after the other, use JavaScript timers to space out setting opacity to 1. Example:

```
var elements = [ /* Image elements to fade */ ];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        elements[i].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1250 * i);
}
```

Comment: Wasn't me!  Thank you, I'm going to try the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function of fadeIn to load other image

```
function fadeIn() {
$("#imageOne").fadeIn("fast",function(){
      $("#imageTwo").fadeIn("fast", function(){
           $("#imageThr").fadeIn("fast");
      });
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with so far.  Unfortunately, I haven't figure how to have them fade in, as the below just makes them appear one after the other.  Though it's pure Javascript.

Any suggestions?

```js
    var imageOne = document.getElementById('imageOne');
 var imageTwo = document.getElementById('imageTwo');
 var imageThr = document.getElementById('imageThr');

 function fadeIn(element) {
  element.style.opacity += 0.9;

  if (element.style.opacity < 1) {
   setTimeout(function() {
    fadeIn(element);
   }, 100);
  }
 }
 setTimeout(function() {
  fadeIn(document.getElementById("imageOne"));
 }, 1000);
 setTimeout(function() {
  fadeIn(document.getElementById("imageTwo"));
 }, 5000);
 setTimeout(function() {
  fadeIn(document.getElementById("imageThr"));
 }, 10000);
```